# Invalid BSON field name $match

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to read the data from one collection and writing to another collection .While inserting the data into another collection by using $merge getting below error .Could you please suggest how to insert the aggregate pipeline data into new collection .

```
 String collectionName = "SampleCollection";

        if (!mongoOps.collectionExists(collectionName)) {
            collectionNew = mongoOps.createCollection(collectionName);
            LOG.info("Collection %s was successfully created", collectionName);
        } else {
            collectionNew = mongoOps.getCollection(collectionName);
        }

        List<? extends Bson> pipeline  = Arrays.asList(
                new Document()
                        .append("$match", new Document()
                                .append("key", "PP")
                                .append("Amount", "RR")
                                
                        ),
                new Document()
                        .append("$addFields", new Document()
                                .append("ID", "$_id")
                                .append("Period", nextPeriod)
                               
                                .append("Type", new Document()
                                        .append("key", "PP")
                                        .append("value", "Statement")
                                )
                                .append("amount", new Document()
                                        .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                "$Amount.amount",
                                                 Decimal128.parse("0.0")
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                              
                             
                                .append("index", true)
                        ),
                new Document()
                        .append("$project", new Document()
                                .append("_id", 0.0)
                                .append("Amt", 0.0)
                                .append("Amount", 0.0)
                                .append("ClearAmount", 0.0)
                        )

        );
        List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList(pipeline);
        //documentList.add(Document.parse(toJson()));
        collectionNew.insertMany(documentList);
```

exception :Invalid BSON field name $match

Comment: `collectionNew.insertMany(documentList);` - that code says you are trying to insert an aggregation pipeline into a collection. Is that what you are trying?

Comment: Yes . I want to insert the aggregate pipeline into new collection and tried different ways but was not able to insert the data into collection and the collection was empty .Can you please suggest if any other way to insert the aggregate results to collection

Comment: What is the version of MongoDB you are working with?

Comment: MongoDB version 4.4 documentation says about field naming restrictions and using `$` as prefixed field names: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/core/document/#field-names . This my be causing the  error.

Comment: I think you need to print `documentList` here to see what your inserted documents actually look like

Comment: Mongodb version is 3.10.1.  I am able to print the documentList length

Comment: Actually I have used $operator for other  scenarios and it is throwing any error .I think while inserting there is some issue